# Can someone translate a German rhyme into English for me?

Tags: translation, phrase, german-to-english

I found a beautiful German antique apothecary glass jar that has a rhyme on it, written in what appears to be an old form of German. Can anyone translate it for me:

> Do ho ich müß'n sechs Pfoff'n mol'n, mög sie olle d'r Teif'l hol'n.

There are hand-painted pictures of an oldish looking fellow with a large nose and wearing glasses, a strange long narrow hat and robe, carrying some sort of cane and holding a piece of paper in front of a snake wrapped around an apple tree. I would really appreciate any help you can give me with this.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 17):

The inscription reads:

> Do ho ich müß'n sechs Pfoff'n mol'n mög sie olle d'r Teif'l hol'n

We have a dialect transcription which in proper German reads as:

> Da habe ich sechs Pfaffen malen müssen, möge sie alle der Teufel holen.

An English translation would then be:

> So I had to draw six shavelings - shall the devil take them all.

Comment: Könnte hinkommen. Mein Versuch war ziemlich ähnlich.

Comment: Good catch, the **ß**.

Comment: @PiedPiper: thank you for the edit of the images to the question, great work. But with all respect I disagree here. *Parson* is not really better. A parson is a proper term for a usually protestant clergyman but *Pfaffen* is a **derogatory** term for a catholic priest. This would also hold true for a *shaveling* (sb. with a shaved head) but it may be a more British term.

Comment: Could you add, just for the record, which dialect it *probably* is?

Comment: @Philipp: unfortunately not - all I can say is that it is a dialect I am unfamiliar with... Frankonian?