# Herkunft von "Du Pfeife"

Tags: meaning, etymology

Inspired by [these "Pfaffen"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9327/can-someone-translate-a-german-rhyme-into-english-for-me), I wonder where the derogatory expression "Pfeife" comes from.

Answer (score 4):

I know this expression, after short search I found an entry in a german ["Mundmische" (regional dialects) dictionary](https://www.mundmische.de/bedeutung/14967-Pfeife). Their Idea is it that the term is referring to the fact that a pipe is hollow. I did not find any other explanations so far.

By the way, Pfeiffe also kann used in another way as "Den kannst du in der Pfeife rauchen" which translates to ["You can smoke him in the pipe"](http://www.mitmachwoerterbuch.lvr.de/liste.php)

Comment: -1 weil das nur Vermutungen sind

Comment: *Hollow* makes sense. That also explains another, similar term: *Flasche* (or as Giovanni Trapattoni once put it: "Flasche leer").

Comment: FWIW, the hollowness is also one of the possible explanations given by the [University of Graz](https://wortschaetze.uni-graz.at/de/wortschaetze/musik/belegdatenbank/p/pfeife/) (number 3).

Comment: Aha, ein Pfeifenkopf!?

Answer (score 4):

Der [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Pfeife) schreibt zur Bedeutung und Herkunft von "Pfeife":

> Bedeutung Pfeife:
>
> - 1a: der Flöte ähnliches, einfaches, kleines, aus einer Röhre mit Mundstück und Grifflöchern bestehendes Musikinstrument)
> - [...]
> - 4: (salopp abwertend) unfähiger, ängstlicher Mensch; Versager
>
> **Herkunft zu 4: wohl zu Pfeife (1a) im Sinne von „Wertloses“; die Pfeife galt als minderwertiges Blasinstrument**
>
> Beispiel zu 4: dieser
> Schiedsrichter ist eine Pfeife

[Wissen.de](https://www.wissen.de/wortherkunft/pfeife) nennt dieselbe Herleitung:

> [...] die heute umgangssprachliche Verwendung von Pfeife für einen
> dummen Menschen beruht wohl auf der früheren Annahme, die Pfeife sei
> ein minderwertiges, einfaches Instrument

Comment: Überraschende Sichtweise des Duden. So minderwertig kann sie ja nicht sein, wenn sie sich über tausende von Jahren gehalten hat...

Comment: @IQV, nur weil etwas weit verbreitet ist und sich lange hält, heißt es nicht, dass es hochwertig ist. Bei mir am Bahnhof würde sich kein Edelrestaurant halten können, die Dönerbude aber gibt es seit Jahren. Trotzdem würde ich nicht behaupten, dass der Döner dort ein hochwertiges Essen ist.

Comment: Dass der Duden aber den Schiri, der in der Tat oft "Pfeife" genannt wird, zur Illustration von "minderweitig" heranzieht, unterschlagend, dass die Trillerpfeife ein wichtiges Instrument des Schiris ist, lässt den Duden mal wieder schlecht aussehen.

Answer (score 1):

I once read somewhere that it comes from a derogative word for the referee in football, as he uses a whistle ("Pfeife"). If he makes bad decisions he is often called a "Pfeife". But no guarantee on this one.

Comment: Ja, das wäre auch meine erste Vermutung gewesen. Die Betonung liegt auf *Vermutung*. Ich vermute, es sei unwahrscheinlich, dass es generell abwertend werden würde und nicht schon vorher so gewesen übertragen worden wäre.

Comment: Ich hege auch keinen Anspruch auf Korrektheit da ich, wie gesagt, keine Quelle vorzuweisen habe. Trotzdem fand ich es wert genannt zu werden.

Comment: Da Fußball noch nicht so alt ist wären ältere Fundstellen interessant. Zu bedenken ist auch, dass früher Schutzmänner mit Pfeifen ausgerüstet waren. Ob militärische, obere Ränge dafür sorgten, dass man nach ihrer Pfeife (i.w.S.) tanzt (i.ü.S.), weiß ich nicht. Dass es ein Spaß ist, den Schiri, der eine Pfeife hat, als Pfeife zu bezeichnen, setzt eigentlich schon die Abwertung voraus.